# No numeric types to aggregate error while plotting bar graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I got a 'No numeric types to aggregate' error when I run the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_labels = ['Female', 'Male']

genderincomeTM1 = round(TM1.groupby('Gender')['Income'].mean())
genderincomeTM2 = round(TM2.groupby('Gender')['Income'].mean())
genderincomeTM3 = round(TM3.groupby('Gender')['Income'].mean())

genderTM1 = genderincomeTM1.index
genderTM2 = genderincomeTM2.index
genderTM3 = genderincomeTM3.index

x = np.arange(len(x_labels))

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

width = 0.35 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bar1 = ax.bar(x - 0.3, genderincomeTM1, width=0.2, label='TM1')
bar2 = ax.bar(x, genderincomeTM2, width=0.2, label='TM2')
bar3 = ax.bar(x + 0.3, genderincomeTM3, width=0.2, label='TM3')

ax.set_title('Average Income by Product Model', fontsize = 18)
ax.set_ylabel('Sales', fontsize = 12)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 90000)
ax.legend(loc=(1.02,0.4), borderaxespad=0, fontsize = 12)

def autolabel(bars):
    for each in bars:
        height = each.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(each.get_x() + each.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 2),  # 2 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(bar1)
autolabel(bar2)
autolabel(bar3)
```

```
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-fb1aa4ae1242> in <module>
      1 x_labels = ['Female', 'Male']
      2 
----> 3 genderincomeTM1 = round(TM1.groupby('Gender')['Income'].mean())
      4 genderincomeTM2 = round(TM2.groupby('Gender')['Income'].mean())
      5 genderincomeTM3 = round(TM3.groupby('Gender')['Income'].mean())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1223         """
   1224         nv.validate_groupby_func("mean", args, kwargs, ["numeric_only"])
-> 1225         return self._cython_agg_general(
   1226             "mean", alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(**kwargs), **kwargs
   1227         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
    906 
    907         if len(output) == 0:
--> 908             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
    909 
    910         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I have removed all empty rows and checked on 'Income' column using is_numeric_dtype. I also converted the column to int.

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
is_numeric_dtype(df['Income'])

>True

df['Income'] = df['Income'].astype(int)
df.info()

><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>Int64Index: 180 entries, 0 to 182
>Data columns (total 10 columns):
> #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
>---  ------         --------------  ----- 
> 0   Product        180 non-null    object
> 1   Branch         180 non-null    object
> 2   Age            180 non-null    object
> 3   Gender         180 non-null    object
> 4   Education      180 non-null    object
> 5   MaritalStatus  180 non-null    object
> 6   Usage          180 non-null    object
> 7   Fitness        180 non-null    object
> 8   Income         180 non-null    int32
```

I am confused why there is no numeric type for Income after validation. Could it be referring to 'Gender'? How should I go about resolving the error?

Comment: this is not really a matplotlib question, the error occurs on the 3rd line, before any plotting happens

Comment: @EMiller How can I fix my 3rd line code so that the error will go away? Would you be able to help?

Comment: @raven I answered your question below. Do let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: It seems as though your groupby function is causing the error. You can see this in line 1224 in your traceback as it looks to be applying the mean to gender.

1224         nv.validate_groupby_func("mean", args, kwargs, ["numeric_only"])

Try creating your grouped objects first (separately) and then performing your calculations on the columns within those grouped objects.

Answer (score 0):

I can't probably answer your question, because you haven't provided a dataframe which reproduces the error.  Maybe you could start by running this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
TM1 = pd.DataFrame({'Gender':['M','F','M','F'],'Income':['10','20','30','40']})
TM1['Income'] = TM1.Income.astype(int)
TM1.groupby('Gender')['Income'].mean().round()
```

Because the incomes are initially given as strings, the mean can't be computed until they're converted to integers.